# Displaying Files and Folders in a GridView for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to make an application that lists folders, subfolders and it's files. The users must be able to view and download the file name. The files will be stored in a database as byte format. I've made an image that shows what the application must be able to do:

[image]

1. list the directories
2. list the files and subdirectories
3. download the file when you click on it

Could this be done using a gridview, or what can I use to do this?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried so far? What specifically is not working?

Comment: @MichaelJasper Actually I'm new to this, so don't where to start, that's why i posted here. If i tried anything then i would post that too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Webforms, here is a nice tutorial by Scott:
[Displaying Files and Folders in a GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513005012/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090110-1.aspx)

You can use this tutorial for referring how to use database to persist file data:
[Save Files to SQL Server Database using FileUpload Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Files-to-SQL-Server-Database-using-FileUpload-Control.aspx)

The idea is that instead of linking the file name to the physical file using  tag, you may have to write a download service (with the file identifier as input.. ex: download.aspx?filename=abcd).

On receiving the request at the server (i.e. in the code behind - download.aspx.cs file, you may have to validate the file name and then read the byte contents stored in database and then write it back to the response.